# How to recursively convert json file to Dictionary<string, dynamic> in dotnet core

Tags: c#, json, swagger, openapi

I have a swagger doc json file and I would like to convert it to an 
`Dictionary<string,dynamic>` with key being the property name and value can be another dictionnary of type  `Dictionary<string,dynamic>`  until the value is a primitive, not a json object.

I started with `var dic = JSonObject.Parse("file.json").Properties().ToDictionary(p=>p.Name, p => p.Value);`

How to recursively test and convert p.Value to dictionnary when the value is not a primitive type?

Comment: could you provide `file.json`?

Comment: json file is not static. It depend on the backend. here is an example of json file https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

Answer (score 0):

I just found this package [Microsoft.OpenApi.Readers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OpenApi.Readers) which already has everything I wanted to parse swagger document and used it like this

```
       string url = "https://localhost:10155/swagger/v1/swagger.json";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
        var openApiDocument = new OpenApiStreamReader().Read(stream, out var diagnostic);
        return View(openApiDocument);
```

Then I could get all the `OpenApiDocument` object in the tree

Answer (score 0):

try this, it is more robust than async concept...

```
private void GetServiceJSONDocument()
{
    Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiDocument JsonDoc = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiDocument();
    HttpWebResponse wresponse = GetServiceAPIRequest(false, SiteAPIURL).GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    JsonDoc = new OpenApiStreamReader().Read(wresponse.GetResponseStream(), out var diagnostic); 
}

private static HttpWebRequest GetServiceAPIRequest(bool isPOST, string atvURL)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(atvURL);
    webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    webRequest.ContentType = atvURL.ToLower().IndexOf(".json") >= 0  ? "application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"" : "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", ActiveWSDLRequest);
    webRequest.Method = !isPOST ? "GET" : "POST";
    return webRequest;
}
```